# How to open html table in xls on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am trying to open html table in xls on click of a button. I already have a way (using javascript) to export the html table in xls through "save as". Here I have to save the resulting xls file and then I can open it. Now I want to improve it so on click of button from html page, the html table should be opened in xls without need for "save as".

This is the javascript I am trying to use:

```
function fnExcelReport() {
    var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Test Sheet</x:Name>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';
    tab_text = tab_text + "<table>";
    var headingTable = $("#tableData").clone();//In my html table id="tableData"
    tab_text = tab_text + headingTable.html();
    tab_text = tab_text + '</table>';
    $('.c_tbl').each(function( index ) {
        tab_text = tab_text + "<table>";
        tab_text = tab_text + "<tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>";
        tab_text = tab_text + '</table>';
        tab_text = tab_text + "<table>";
        var exportTable = $(this).clone();
        tab_text = tab_text + exportTable.html();
        tab_text = tab_text + '</table>';
    });
    tab_text = tab_text + '</body></html>';
    var fileName = name + '.xls';
    var blob = new Blob([tab_text], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8" })
    window.saveAs(blob, wo_var + ".xls");
}
```

From html I am trying to call this function fnExcelReport() using:

```
<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();">Open as Excel</button>
```

But I keep getting following error:

```
openInExcel.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at fnExcelReport (openInExcel.js:8)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Test.html:103)
```

Google search for this error shows you cannot put the script reference to jquery-ui before the jquery script itself. But I am not using JQuery. Other things I tried still give the same error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" just at different line number due to changes.

1. I tried adding:

   $(document).ready(function(){
   });

   And add call to function fnExcelReport() inside document ready.
2. Also tried including whole function fnExcelReport() inside document ready and then adding `$("#btnExport").click(fnExcelReport);` before closing document ready. For this removed `onclick="fnExcelReport();"` from button element.

Both above methods still give same error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

Can someone help me find what I am doing wrong or suggest any alternate way to get this done?

Comment: _"But I am not using JQuery."_ ? `var headingTable = $("#tableData").clone();`, `$('.c_tbl').each(function( index ) {})`

Comment: Oh, So I am using it unknowingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you *are* using jQuery: the $ is an alias to the jQuery() function. If I were you, I would either include jQuery (from the CDN):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, you can rewrite these lines:

```
var headingTable = $("#tableData").clone();//In my html table id="tableData"
tab_text = tab_text + headingTable.html();
....
$('.c_tbl').each(function( index ) {
....
var exportTable = $(this).clone();
```

as:

```
var headingTable = document.getElementById('tableData').cloneNode(true);
tab_text = tab_text + headingTable.innerHTML;
....
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('c_tbl');
for(var i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
....
var exportTable = els[i].cloneNode(true);
tab_text = tab_text + exportTable.innerHTML;
```

### If you want to use the FileSaver.js library:

Include the library from the CDN in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```

Change your JS to this:

```
var blob = new Blob([tab_text], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8" });
saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Will. I did try including JQuery as you suggested but got error at line:
window.saveAs(blob, wo_var + ".xls");
Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: wo_var is not defined

So I made the change as below:
window.saveAs(blob, fileName);
and now I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: window.saveAs is not a function

I can't figure out why it's happening to I am trying to put html and java script both in a simple example to see if it helps.

Comment: So window.saveAs is not entirely supported yet, and the workarounds are complicated. IE/Edge have [msSaveBlob and msSaveOrOpenBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx), and Firefox and Chrome require a more complicated JS function to get it to work (see [this blog](https://muaz-khan.blogspot.com/2012/10/save-files-on-disk-using-javascript-or.html) and [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/)).

I think the best way to do this is to use the [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) library. I'll put that solution in my answer above.