# Open HTML table in excel without save as

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I want to open html table from an html page in excel sheet without having to save the excel sheet first. I could find a couple ways to save the html table in excel sheet first and then open it.

I can either modify one these approaches I have or can take entirely new approach as well.

Here is HTML I have as of now (smallest use case to explain what I tried):

I tried to create jsfiddle for demo but it seems document.write is not allowed there. Regardless here is the link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/vg1o3vq6/1/).

Note: I had tried doing this with another option I had found and the had to ask for help with that as well. The link to that question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567983/how-to-open-html-table-in-xls-on-click-of-a-button)

Forgive me if I am being too needy but I can't seem to find a solution through surfing so I am trying what I did find which was similar but unable to tweak it.

```js
function fnExcelReport() {
  var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
  var textRange;
  var j = 0;
  tab = document.getElementById('tableData'); // id of table

  for (j = 0; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
    tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
    /*tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";*/
  }

  tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
  /*tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table*/
  tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
  tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

  if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer
  {
    txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
    txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
    txtArea1.document.close();
    txtArea1.focus();
    sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "download.xls");
  } else //other browser not tested on IE 11
    sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

  return (sa);
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>Heading2</h1>
</center>

<table id="tableData">
  <tr>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
    <th>Header3</th>
    <th>Header4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text1</td>
    <td>93</td>
    <td>4343</td>
    <td>1243</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text2</td>
    <td>103</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text3</td>
    <td>932</td>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>3545</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text4</td>
    <td>933</td>
    <td>21348</td>
    <td>7563</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text5</td>
    <td>9383</td>
    <td>576</td>
    <td>230</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text6</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>354</td>
    <td>345</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--</br><button id="btnExport" onclick="window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML));">Export To Excel</button></br></br></br></br> COMMENT: No need for exportExcel.js if I use this way -->
<!--</br><button id="btnExport" onclick="window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + document.getElementById('tableData').outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20'));">Export To Excel</button></br></br></br></br> COMMENT: No need for exportExcel.js if I use this way -->
</br><button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();">Export To Excel</button></br>
</br>
</br>
</br>
```

Comment: I created you a snippet which does not work either since SO does not allow popups - ps why not look for `txtArea1.document.execCommand` instead of testing IE useragent?

Comment: [Here's a link to plunkr, which appears to allow the popups](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q6oCB8MiMmufmCliNdVT?p=preview)

Comment: Well this will never work: `txtArea1.document.open("txt/html",` it is text/html but that is not actually what you want

Comment: Thank you Jhecht for the plunker link. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my first approach which was using JQuery and FileSaver.min.js library. So I decided to use that approach as it does what I wanted. The link to my question and answer from Will Jobs is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567983/how-to-open-html-table-in-xls-on-click-of-a-button/42568196?noredirect=1#comment72315152_42568196)

Thank you for your time and inputs mplungjan, Jhecht